# Exception Specifications on VS2012

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, exception

I recently updated to Visual Studio 2012 and I am having some issues with exception specifications. 
I keep getting errors on system files that have the form

```
<some type> function(<some input>) _NOEXCEPT    
{
  <some code>
}
```

where

```
 #define _NOEXCEPT  throw()
```

I don't quite understand why I get the errors, since the macro is defined and the use is as defined by [Visual Studio Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx). The errors are something like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\list(1119): error C2059: syntax error : '{'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\list(1119): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

Lines 1118-1121 of the "list" file from above are:

```
const_iterator begin() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return iterator for beginning of nonmutable sequence
    return (const_iterator(this->_Nextnode(this->_Myhead), this));
    }
```

Errors come from "list" and "xtree", both located in the above path. 
I've tried changing the "\EH" flag as specified in the link above but that did not help.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

**EDIT:** Adding preprocessor file excerpt.

```
const_iterator begin() const {printf("ERROR: %s\n     in file %s at line %d\n", ,"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\VC\\include\\list",1118); throw(1);}
    {   
    return (const_iterator(this->_Nextnode(this->_Myhead), this));
    }
```

Not sure what I should make out of this file but here is the example code.

Comment: Use C/C++, Preprocessor, Generate Preprocessed File = Yes to see what that *really* turns into.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I went ahead and created the preprocessor file. I pasted a piece of the code that I think generates the error. I am not sure, since I don't know what I am looking for. Can you tell me more?

Comment: Well, that doesn't look much like `throw()`, does it?  You'll need to find the #define that whacks that _NOEXCEPT macro.  Right-click it, Go To Definition.

Comment: going to the definition: `#define _NOEXCEPT throw ()` in some other file. I assumed the last part of the brace was okay, where `throw()` got changed to `throw(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

As it turns out, there was a global header with macro

```
#define throw(message) {printf("ERROR: %s\n in file %s at line %d\n", message,__FILE__,__LINE__); throw(1);}
```

which was causing all the problems. undefining the macro causes things to work out nicely.

---

I gave up on trying to figure this out...
As a work around I redefined the _NOEXCEPT macro to not use throw, i.e.

```
#define _NOEXCEPT
```

in the header files that were causing problems.

I don't think it will be a major issue since all compilers ignore the exception specification and is deprecated in c++11

Comment: Historically, VS compiler did not ignore empty exception specification `throw()`. It did affect code generation.